# Hide Messages / Log File in texstudio

Tags: texstudio

It is possible to make use of textstudio and avoid to generate that annoying "Messages / Log File" window?. I tried to do something in Quick Build options without success.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Can you post a screen shot of the options pane as you have set it?

Answer (score 2):

When you just press the close button on the window it won't reappear until an error or warning occurs. At least that's what happens on my computer.